# 3D texture to animation using Python

Tags: python, animation, 3d

I want to convert a 3D texture to a simple 3D animation using python. So basically, applying the 3D texture to a moving 3D object in Python.

Does anybody know if there is a library that can help me do that ? I am familiar with python but don't know that much about 3D.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use libraries like PyOpenGL or Pyglet in Python to achieve this. These libraries provide functionalities for rendering 3D objects and textures.

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

def load_texture(filename):
    texture_surface = pygame.image.load(filename)
    texture_data = pygame.image.tostring(texture_surface, "RGB", 1)
    width, height = texture_surface.get_rect().size

    texture_id = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data)

    return texture_id

def draw_cube(texture_id):
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 1)
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1)
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1)

    # Define other faces similarly
    
    glEnd()

def draw_scene(texture_id):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
    glRotatef(1, 1, 1, 1)  # Rotate the cube
    draw_cube(texture_id)
    glutSwapBuffers()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    glutInit()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    texture_id = load_texture("texture.png")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        draw_scene(texture_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I want to apply a texture to a 3D Tshirt obejct, I bhave to draw the t'shirt using OpenGL ?
What if I want the T'shirt to move ?

Comment: Using OpenGL, you can do that too. 
Also if somewhere my above answer is helpful to you, please mark it as correct. Thank you